# How to manage RFID

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm actually writing a program that will control RFID by taking employees' Arrival dates and hours at work and what time they left work. I want the program to first take the date and hour when it first reads a tag and give the exit time when it reads the tag for the second time.
Hello, I'm actually writing a program that will control RFID by taking employees' Arrival dates and hours at work and what time they left work. I want the program to first take the date and hour when it first reads a tag and give the exit time when it reads the tag for the second time

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.comm.*;

class RFIDTagRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener, extend Transportation {
static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static Enumeration portList;

InputStream inputStream;



SerialPort serialPort;
Thread readThread;
//tableau consisting of SOH, length, command, data, BCC
static byte[] bytearray = {0x01, 0x02, 0x09, 0x32, 0x39};

static OutputStream outputStream;
static int n =0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Enumerate a list of available ports
portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
// Identify the ports. I connected the reader with COM1
while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
if (portId.getName().equals("COM1")) {
System.out.println("The port is: " + portId.getName());
RFIDTagRead reader = new RFIDTagRead();
}
}

}
}
public RFIDTagRead() {
try {
//Open the COM1 port and name it MicroReader with timeout 2000ms
serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
} catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("Port Error");}
try {
outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
// Write the stream of data conforming to PC to reader protocol
outputStream.write(bytearray);
outputStream.flush();

System.out.println("The following bytes are being written");
for(int i=0; i<bytearray.length; i++)
System.out.println(bytearray[i]);
System.out.println("Tag will be read when its in the field of the reader");
} catch (IOException e) {}
// Set Serial Port parameter
try {
serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
} catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {}
try {
//Register an event listener object to the port
serialPort.addEventListener(this);
} catch (TooManyListenersException e)
{System.out.println("Too Many Listeners");
}
//Specify an event type. On data availability, triggers serialEvent method
serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
try {
//Associate an InputStream object with this port.
inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {}
//Start a thread to handle the time-to-read the tag
readThread = new Thread(this);
readThread.start();
}
public void run() {
try {
Thread.sleep(56);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
//This method is called by notifyOnDataAvailabe()
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
switch(event.getEventType()) {
case SerialPortEvent.BI:
case SerialPortEvent.OE:
case SerialPortEvent.FE:
case SerialPortEvent.PE:
case SerialPortEvent.CD:
case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
case SerialPortEvent.RI:
case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
break;
case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
n++; //to count the number of readings
System.out.println("The reading description of RFID Tag" + " " + n);
//array size must not be less than the number of bytes to be read
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20]; // to store the read data
int numbyte = 0;
try {
while(inputStream.available() >0) {
// Read the RFID data and store in the byte array
numbyte = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
System.out.println("Number of Bytes read: " + numbyte);
}
} catch (IOException e) {}
if( readBuffer[0] == 1) /*check if start bit is detected */
{
int length = readBuffer[1];
// Identify the Transponder type
switch(readBuffer[2]) {
case 12 :
{
System.out.print("RFID is RO:" + "\t");
break;
}
case 13 :
{
System.out.print("RFID is R/W:" + "\t");
break;
}
case 14:
{
System.out.print("RFID is MPT/SAMPT:" + "\t");
break;
}
case 15:
{
System.out.print("RFID is Other:" + "\t");
break;
}
}
// Write the actual tag reading in Hexadecimal
for( int m = length+1; m > 2; m--)
System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(readBuffer[m] & 255));
}
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("\t" + "Read Sucessful");
System.out.println("----------------------------------");
break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Okay, so where are you stuck? Can you specify what your question is?

Comment: I dont how how to make the scanner output arrival date and hour when it first reads the tag and leave date when it reads the tag for the second time

Comment: So in other words, you don't know how to read the rfid scanner?